# Create user account

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a new user with `CREATE USER admin@localhost;`, but it doesn't work so far. I got the error `ERROR 1819 (HY000): Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements`. However, that error talk about the password, but I didn't enter any password.

Could anyone be able to tell me what's wrong with that?

Comment: Exactly . . . .

Comment: The error might lead us to suspect that "the current policy requirements" are somehow *requiring* that a password be provided when a user is created. Have you considered *supplying* a password? As shown in the first example  `CREATE USER 'finley'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';`  in the MySQL Reference Manual  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-users.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is so straight forward but you need specify password...

below is the syntax

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'localhost'
    -> IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
```

For more, here is the ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/assigning-passwords.html